# how to extract json data to populate checklist dropdown plugin

Tags: jquery, json

I'm using the jquery checkbox dropdown plugin for the multiple selection with json data of the format:

```
{"message":[{"id":"xyz","name":"USERA"},{"id":"abc","name":"USERB"}]}
```

I tried to populate the drop down with the json data but I haven't been able to succeed. Any help is appreciated.

Please find below the method I was using to populate the dropdown list:

```
$.ajax({type : "GET",
        url : "",
        data : "",
        dataType : "json",
        success : function(data) {

            var Options = '';
            $.each($(data.message), function() {

                Options +='<option value="'+this.name+'">'+this.name+'</option>'
            });
            $("#dropdown1").append(Options);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Are there any JS errors?  Any other errors?  What exactly is not working?

Answer (score 0):

This line -

```
$.each($(data.message), function() { ... }
```

Should be something like this -

```
$.each(data.message), function(index,elem) { ... });
```

Then the line that you use to concatenate the HTML should appear like this -

```
Options +='<option value="'+elem.name+'">'+elem.name+'</option>';
```

Also you were missing a semicolon on the line with `Options +=`.

Comment: Is `#dropdown1` a valid SELECT element?

Comment: Is the ajax call returning data at all?

Comment: Ok... can you post your server side code that deals with sending the data?

Comment: If the AJAX code is not returning any data then your `$.each` function will not execute.  The code you posted looks fine to me.  I have to assume that the problem is with the response from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({type : "GET",
        url : "",
        data : "",
        dataType : "json",
        success : function(data) {

            $.each($(data.message), function(index,val) {

               $('#dropdown1').append($("<option></option>").val(val.name).html(val.name));
            });

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured-out  wat went wrong in my code.. 
dropdownchecklist() had to be called just after appending the data,like

```
success : function(data) {
     var Options = '';
     $.each($(data.message), function() {
         Options +='<option value="'+this.name+'">'+this.name+'</option>'
     });
     $("#dropdown1").append(Options);
     $("#dropdown1").dropdownchecklist();
}
```